# GUI calclution in JGrasp

Tags: swing, jgrasp

1. I want to perform some calculation by clicking in convert button and the answer will be displayed in the number text field.
2. also, I have an `Exception` , I did not know how to solve it

this is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class MyEvent implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    System.out.println("Button Clicked ");  
    System.exit(0);
}
}
class Clacluting{
public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException{
    Frame frm = new Frame("TASK # 3");


    TextField txt[] = { new TextField(15), new TextField(9),
                            };
    Label lab[] ={new Label("number"), new Label("Amount")};
    Button b = new Button("Convert");
    Button b2 = new Button("Reset");
    frm.setSize(200,250);
    frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    double calculat=0;
    calculat= Double.parseDouble(txt[0].getText()) * 0.381793;

    txt[1].setText(String.valueOf(calculat));

    b.addActionListener(new MyEvent());
    b2.addActionListener(new MyEvent());
    frm.setSize(200,250);
    frm.add( lab[0]);
    frm.add(txt[0]);
    frm.add( lab[1]);
    frm.add( txt[1]);
    frm.add(b);
    frm.add(b2);
    frm.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Comment: What type of exception are you getting? show us the stack trace (TIP: use: `e.printStackTrace()`;)

Comment: this one:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:994)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
 at Sarah.main(Sarah.java:25)